# Caching the response

Tags: slim

Here is the controller code i use to:

- Send user to home view
- Generate a (cache) html file containing the final response code

Would this be the right way to do so concerning the cache ? I'm not sure if the rewind function is for. Please enlighten me:

```
public function index( Request $request, Response $response )
    {
        $view = '/src/views/home.php';

        $this->render( $response, Settings::ABSPATH . $view );
        $body = $response->getBody();
        $body->rewind();
        $html = $body->getContents();
        file_put_contents( Settings::ABSPATH . '/tmp/cachePages/home.html', $html );
        return;
    }
```

Comment: This is Slim3 right?

Comment: yes this is slim 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When there is only the response from the rendered page, you can use the method [`PhpRenderer::fetch()`](https://github.com/slimphp/PHP-View/blob/master/src/PhpRenderer.php#L148). That returns the rendered output, so you do not need to do this stuff on the `Response`-object

```
$view = Settings::ABSPATH . '/src/views/home.php';
$html = $renderer->fetch($view);
```

The other option is to use the [Twig-View](https://github.com/slimphp/Twig-View) which already provides functionallity for caching.